# TextSwitcherActivity, cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-sqlite, textswitcher

thank you.
I wanted to add a simple TextSwitcher to a fragment, it's all good (I think) till this line:

```
TextView t = new TextView (TextSwitcherActivity.this);
```

I am missing out why it cannot resolve the symbol: TextSwitcherActivity.
Please, if  you have any suggestions I would truly appreciate.

Here is the whole Java code, I believe is by the book, nothing new.

```
public class viewOne extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextSwitcher switching;
    Button pre_button, next_button;
    String strTextSwitcher[] = {"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3, Text 4", "Text demo 5"};
    int currentIndex = -1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_view_one);
        next_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        pre_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pre_button);
        switching=(TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.switching);
        switching.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {

            public View makeView() {

                TextView t = new TextView (TextSwitcherActivity.this);
                t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER);
                t.setTextSize(36);
                return t;
            }
        });
        switching.setCurrentText("click on the next button to switch text");
        pre_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
                    public void onClick(View view){
                if (currentIndex>0)
                    switching.setText(strTextSwitcher[currentIndex]);
            }
        });
        next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (currentIndex<strTextSwitcher.length-1)
                    currentIndex = currentIndex+1;
                switching.setText(strTextSwitcher[currentIndex]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use your current activity context. `viewOne.this` or simply `this`.

Comment: I think you need to use viewOne.this?

Comment: Please check which type `TextView` constructor expects as 1st parameter. Don't put there whatever first comes to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
TextView t = new TextView (this);
//or
TextView t = new TextView (viewOne.this);
```